# 4G modem works only on LiveCD in Fedora

Tags: fedora, networkmanager, livecd, modem, huawei

I run Fedora 24 as LiveCD (XFCE spin) and my 4G usb-modem works great.

Then I installed Fedora on my hard disk and the modem does not work.

On LiveCD NetworkManager automatically recognized the modem as mobile broadband, but if I run my system from hard disk, NetworkManager does not recognize my modem.

By the way, I see my modem after `lsusb` command in the list.

I do not understand why this happens, because the OS is the same.

The modem type: Huawei E3372h

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a driver that the LiveCD has is not installed or not active in your installed system. When booted to the LiveCD, run `lsmod` and make a ntoe of what driver name is used by your modem's network device. Assuming that device name is `eth0`, you would see a line that looks something like:

```
<drivername>          16384  1 eth0
```

Once you have the driver name, boot to your hard disk version, and if you check `lsmod` I'm pretty sure you won't see that driver name in the output. If you don't, run `modprobe <drivername>` to load the driver, and your modem interface should them be available. To make it persist across reboots, you need to edit `/etc/modprobe.conf` (this file may not yet exist) or add a file to the `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory, adding the directive `install <drivername>` to ensure that driver gets loaded at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Huawei E3372h is supported by [ModemManager](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ModemManager) ( support a large list of Huawei modems), to install it run the following commands:

```
dnf install ModemManager
systemctl start ModemManager
systemctl enable ModemManager
```

Plug in your modem ,  it will be recognized by Network-Manager.

Answer (score 0):

`usb-modeswitch` is missing on the ARM build of Fedora, so you have to install it. 
It is basically a solution to flip-flop devices. 
When device is connected and the OS has no driver to handle it, dev shows as "ISO9660 drive" with driver inside it. 
When driver is being installed it switches dev to serial mode.

Note that the command name differs from the package name (`usb_modeswitch`). 
When mode switch is configured, you should see in kernel log "GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0" (if you have "option" module loaded)

```
dnf install usb_modeswitch
```

You may need to install wwan plugin for NetworkManager since it isn't included by default

```
dnf install NetworkManager-wwan
```

You should not have problems with modules not being compiled as on Ubuntu and Fedora all optional drivers are compiled as modules. 
But you can load it manually using `modprobe`:

```
modprobe usbnet
modprobe cdc_ncm
modprobe cdc_wdm
modprobe usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x14fe
modprobe option
modprobe huawei_cdc_ncm
modprobe usb_wwan
```

Check your VID (vendor id) & PID (product id) with `lsusb`. Connect to the WAN using:

```
mmcli -m 0 --simple-connect="apn=<APN address>"
```

You can check if modem is connected by running `mmcli -m 0`

Turn on interface:

```
ip link set wwan0 up
```

Set up IP address using DHCP:

```
dhclient wwan0
```

Set DNS Server:

```
systemd-resolve --interface wwan0 --set-dns 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: What is "conventer"? It looks like a typo.

Answer (score -1):

It was due to bug(s) in kernel 4.4.x

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1354142
- https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/48143

etc.

I updated my kernel up to 4.7 and the modem works great.